# How to WCF iis hosted application to run without any network call ?

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, iis

I wrote some WCF application that expose restful service.

This application bring the information from file and on any restful call its return some data from this file.

I trying to make my application to read the file before any first restful call but i can't find any way to do it.

The only thing that i found is to popup the reading file method on the first time that any restful method will call - and by define the WCF interface as

```
   [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

I don't need to read again and again from the file - and i can use one reading and keep the data on the memory.

But the first reading .. this can't be done in the restful method call

Any help please ..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using global.asax

The global.asax file is also known as the ASP.NET “HTTP” application file. It is an optional file and if there is one, it needs to be in the root of an ASP.NET application. It contains code to handle application-level events raised by ASP.NET or HttpModules. It is tightly coupled with the ASP.NET HTTP pipeline.

You will want to utilize the Application_Start method.

Comment: how i define the Application_Start ? i don't see any ASP.NET application file. How can i add it to the project ?

Comment: using Visual Studio you should be able to right click and add new item in the root of the project.  asax should be an option in the dialog and it will have the empty methods for you to implement.

Comment: there is two option 1. ASP.NET Handler 2. ASP.NET Module => witch of them i need to use ?

Comment: If you search for "global application class" in the Add New Item dialog, you should find what you are looking for.